# Setting up dependencies on Visual C++ 2008 Express

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, build-process

How do I set up Visual C++ 2008 Express to point to the required libraries and include directories of a 3rd party C library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For the header files:

1. Right click on the project in the Solution Explorer
2. Choose Properties
3. Expand C/C++
4. Click on General
5. Add your required libraries to Additional Dependencies

#### For the Libraries:

1. Right click on the project in the Solution Explorer
2. Choose Properties
3. Expand Linker
4. Click on Input
5. Add your required libraries to Additional Dependencies

You may also need to the the Additional Library Directories under Linker -> General

Comment: I had to remove the images from your post because ImageShack has deleted them and replaced them with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the project, go to Properties.

Point to the header files with Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories

Point to the library with Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories.  Then tell the linker which libraries you want on the Linker > Input tab, under Additional Dependencies.